# Simple Caesar Cipher C++

Tags: c++, performance, caesar-cipher

I was surprised to learn that there [are not many](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caesar-cipher%20c%2B%2B) C++ Caesar ciphers on Code Review (3 others as of this question). And none that work in this fashion.

Here's the code:

```
// Caesar cipher

#include <iostream>

const char chars[] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};

// Find position in array
int findPosition(char x){
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i <= 25; i++){
        if(x == chars[i]){
            break;
        }
    }

    return i;

}


// Change char to next in array, loop back if at end
char nextChar(char x){
    if(findPosition(x) == 25){
        return chars[0];
    }

    return chars[findPosition(x) + 1];
}

// Rotate char desired amount
char rotChar(char x, int rotNum){
    for(int i = 1; i <= rotNum; i++){
        x = nextChar(x);
    }

    return x;
}

int main(){
    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);

    std::cout << '\n';

    for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++){
        std::cout << "ROT" << i << " - ";

        for(int k = 0; str[k] != '\0'; k++){
            std::cout << rotChar(str[k], i);
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is a *very* simple Caesar cipher. It currently ignores anything uppercase or non-alphabetic.

Here's an example output:

```
ROT0 - helloworld
ROT1 - ifmmpxpsme
ROT2 - jgnnqyqtnf
ROT3 - khoorzruog
ROT4 - lippsasvph
ROT5 - mjqqtbtwqi
ROT6 - nkrrucuxrj
ROT7 - olssvdvysk
ROT8 - pmttwewztl
ROT9 - qnuuxfxaum
ROT10 - rovvygybvn
ROT11 - spwwzhzcwo
ROT12 - tqxxaiadxp
ROT13 - uryybjbeyq
ROT14 - vszzckcfzr
ROT15 - wtaadldgas
ROT16 - xubbemehbt
ROT17 - yvccfnficu
ROT18 - zwddgogjdv
ROT19 - axeehphkew
ROT20 - byffiqilfx
ROT21 - czggjrjmgy
ROT22 - dahhksknhz
ROT23 - ebiiltloia
ROT24 - fcjjmumpjb
ROT25 - gdkknvnqkc
```

How can this code be improved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Function by function review

#### findPosition()

This function is inefficient because it searches an alphabetized string trying to find the index of a lowercase letter.  It would be faster to not even use the string and just compute the position directly like this:

```
if (x >= 'a' && x <= 'z')
    return x - 'a';
```

The other problem is what to return if the input character is not found.  Currently you return 26 and this causes the caller to print a null character (because `chars[26]` is the end of the string).  I think it would be preferable to return -1 and have the caller detect and deal with that.  So in total:

```
int findPosition(char x)
{
    if (x >= 'a' && x <= 'z')
        return x - 'a';
    return -1;
}
```

#### nextChar()

This function works fine, but it gets called `n` times, where `n` is the number of times you are rotating.  You should be able to delete this function if you modified `rotChar()` appropriately.

#### rotChar()

Instead of calling `nextChar()` `rotNum` times, you should be able to use the modulo operator to compute the next character in one step:

```
// Rotate char desired amount
char rotChar(char x, int rotNum)
{
    int pos = findPosition(x);

    if (pos == -1)
        return x;
    return 'a' + ((pos + rotNum) % 26);
}
```

Notice that this also returns the character unmodified if it wasn't a lowercase character.  At this point, you might want to just eliminate `findPosition()` and just do everything in `rotChar()` like this:

```
// Rotate char desired amount
char rotChar(char x, int rotNum)
{
    if (x >= 'a' && x <= 'z')
        return 'a' + (((x - 'a') + rotNum) % 26);
    return x;
}
```

Then you could easily extend this to handle uppercase letters as well:

```
// Rotate char desired amount
char rotChar(char x, int rotNum)
{
    if (x >= 'a' && x <= 'z')
        return 'a' + (((x - 'a') + rotNum) % 26);
    if (x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z')
        return 'A' + (((x - 'A') + rotNum) % 26);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes the code much nicer on the eyes! I especially like how it returns the same character if it is non-alphabetic, I wish I had thought of that. Doing it this way also adds support for rotating numbers, but that isn't common with Caesar ciphers.

Comment: Note that this code only works on platforms where `a..z` are contiguous in the execution character set. This is not guaranteed by C++.

Comment: @RolandIllig When would it not be contiguous in the execution character set?

Comment: @Idempotence I think he is concerned about [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), which is an outdated character encoding.  You can read [this stackoverflow question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381067/does-c-and-c-guarantee-the-ascii-of-a-f-and-a-f-characters) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Magic numbers are bad. What is this `25` everywhere? Were does it stem from? What does it mean? Of course, that's the number of characters in your alphabet, but the stray number `25` doesn't show that information.

So we should change that:

```
const int ALPHABET_SIZE = 26; // see better version below
```

Also, make sure that your alphabet has a good name. It's a global constant variable:

```
const char ALPHABET[] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
```

But we should make sure that `ALPHABET_SIZE` is always in sync with `ALPHABET`, so we should use

```
const int ALPHABET_SIZE = sizeof ALPHABET / sizeof char;
```

Next, your `findPosition` returns invalid values if the character isn't in the alphabet. That can then lead to problems if you use `ALPHABET[26]`. But that's hard too catch since `i` lives too long:

```
// Find position in array
int findPosition(char x){
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i <= 25; i++){
        if(x == ALPHABET[i]){
            break;
        }
    }
    return i; // <---  i might be 26 here
}
```

Try to minimize the scope of a variable. Note that you should come up with some kind of "error" return value if the character is not in your alphabet. `-1` is often used in the C world:

```
const int INVALID = -1;

// Find position in array
int findPosition(char x){
    for(int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++){
        if(x == ALPHABET[i]){
            return i;
        }
    }

    return INVALID; // cannot return an invalid 'i' here, since 'i' is out of scope
}
```

Now you have to check whether the position is actually valid:

```
char nextChar(char x){
    const int position = findPosition(x);
    if(position == INVALID) {
        return x;
    } else if (position == ALPHABET_SIZE){
        return chars[0];
    }

    return ALPHABET[position + 1];
}
```

Note that your code called `findPosition` twice. Your `rotChar` is fine, apart from the fact that most C/C++ programmer use `i = 0` and `i < upperLimit` instead of `i = 1; i <= upperLimit`. But that's personal preference.

What's not fine is the overhead. You should merge both `nextChar` and `rotChar` into a single function:

```
char rotChar(char x, int rotNum) {
    const int position = findPosition(x);

    if(position == INVALID) {
        return x;
    }

    return ALPHABET[(position + rotNum) % ALPHABET_SIZE];
}
```

We end up with the following code:

```
const char ALPHABET[] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
const int ALPHABET_SIZE = sizeof ALPHABET / sizeof char;

const int INVALID = -1;

int findPosition(char x){
    for(int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++){
        if(x == ALPHABET[i]){
            return i;
        }
    }

    return INVALID;
}

char rotChar(char x, int rotNum) {
    const int position = findPosition(x);

    if(position == INVALID) {
        return x;
    }

    return ALPHABET[(position + rotNum) % ALPHABET_SIZE];
}
```

Your `main` can stay the same, but I wouldn't put one character after another. Instead, write a function

```
std::string rotString(std::string);
```

that rotates a string at once, so that you can transform a whole line instead of a single character.